# Twitter Typeahead.js: Launch Javascript function when click on the "notFound" template

Tags: typeahead.js

I want to launch a Javascript function when click on the "notFound" template.

I have a template like this:

```
  notFound: [
    '<div class="js-not-found">',
      '<strong>Not found.</strong>',
    '</div>'
  ]
```

And a Jquery script like this:

```
$(".js-not-found").click(function() {
  alert("empty");
});
```

But it doesn't work. It seems like typeahead is preventing the use of the "click" event.

Any help?

I'm using typeahead.js 0.11.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to have the click handler like below because `.js-not-found` is a dynamically added element.

```
$('mytypeahead-input').on('click', '.js-not-found', function() { //  your typeahead input reference mytypeahead-input
  alert("empty");
});
```